# Можно ли взять Context приложения из класса не активити?

Tags: java, android

Беру `Context` приложения

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
```

Из Активити обращаюсь к стороннему классу и передаю туда context:

```
LS ls = new LS();
ls.setContext(context);
```

Что надо прописать в классе LS, чтобы он при создании брал Context приложения без метода `setContext`?

Comment: передавать в конструкторе класса? или в чем вопрос .. классы - не наследники контекста, не могут "родить" из себя контекст, его можно только передать туда

Comment: А как мне в стороннем классе LS взять контекст приложения? Например чтобы получить доступ к папке с файлами приложения, без передачи его в класс LS .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант, можно переопределить класс `Application`:

```
public class App extends Application {
    private static Context sInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        sInstance = this;
    }

    public static Context getInstance() {
        return sInstance;
    }
}
```

И далее в конструкторе класса `LS` инициализировать соответствующее поле:

```
public class LS {
    private Context mAppContext;

    public LS() {
        mAppContext = App.getInstance();
    }
}
```

Но вообще, имхо, нет необходимости хранить `ApplicationContext` в отдельном поле. Когда к нему нужен доступ, просто получите его с помощью `App.getInstance()`.

Как дополнение: **при передаче ссылки на активити куда-либо, будьте очень осторожны, ибо это чревато утечками памяти.**

Comment: Плохой пример, вторую часть лучше убрать, чтоб никто не видел, а в первой сделать public static volatile, баз instance . У вас в двух местах проглядывается возможность на лик. И желательно название давать понятные, типо AppContext, это тоже очень важно

Comment: `вторую часть лучше убрать` – вторая – это какая именно и почему? Насчет `volatile` пока думаю, а вот с `public` не согласен, ибо нарушается ООП. Где проглядывается возможность мемори лик? По поводу названий согласен, но, имхо, вполне очевидно, что за `Context` хранится в `Application`.

Comment: Это совет, судите сами. App.getinstance != App.context, как раз по ООП вы путаете, ибо получение инстанса класса это другое. А вот второй вариант App.context прозрачен, вы работаете с контекстом классом. Есть ещё один трик, если вы хотите внутри Application сделать singltone, то по сути сам по себе класс и есть уже синлтон, зачем чтото придумывать. Если бы у вас было низкоуровневое ядро и вы держали конект чз JNI, в этом классе, что вы бы каждый раз создавали бы экземпляр? Конечно нет, это очевидная ошибка, тогда вопрос чем app отличается от Android Core, для этого и есть класс Application.

Comment: Да и в любом случае даже ребята с Android знают эту проблему, в последнее время они неплохо разширили класс ContextCompact думаете с проста? Как раз чтоб было удобней, конечно это решает ряд проблем для работы с ресурсами, но не все, вообщем... В любом случае пример не очень удачный, желаю чтоб вам попался опытный напарник на CR.